How to use C005 timer chip?
According to the literature has 6 main pins which have power, trigger, output and ground with the other two main pins being for a resistor that sets the time that the output remains high for.

I guess I got the drawing wrong, so my question is what mosfet can I use for switching a 4.2v lipo cell off after a set period of time, currently in the scheme of things, 10 mins = approx 2 M ohm.
What is supposed to happen is the power switch KS1 is turned on, the C005 gets poer and starts doing its thing with the output pin 3 letting the mosfet switch on, each press of SW1 causes the C005 to be reset and timing starts again.
So which Mosfet would be suited to my needs as I am completely lost on what I should use. its a low gate voltage.
For clarity, I dew the drawing as last time I used an image, it caused a problem, so I drew the drawing.
Edit: Images from a typical Aliexpress seller:


(Baidu datasheet link does not appear to be working)

Could you please provide a link to the datasheet?

There isn't one, the only data I have is from the Ali Express site. The pins are as stated 4 = Power 3 = output 2 = trigger 1 = 0v (gnd) and the other two pins = time based on resistance.

your title is very bad. Please actually describe the question you want to ask in the title!

@MarkGiblin a component without a datasheet is actually a "no-go", and considering timer ICs are very cheap in regular electronics distributors that have a datasheet for every component they sell, I wouldn't know why I'd ever by something more expensive via aliexpress.

You need to have TRIGGER at 0V to have it start when power is applied.
I think this will work, but no guarantees. It should re-trigger on release of SW1 (after press).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The MOSFET I suggested will work for moderate currents, certainly up to 1A.
If you want it to stay off and trigger only when the switch is pressed, then swap the 10kΩ resistor and the switch. It should then re-trigger when the switch is pressed.
Cute little low-voltage (5V maximum) digital counter CMOS variation on the 555 if you don't need high voltage or much output current but do want a long delay time. I found some information in English here. There may also be packaged chips available in SO8 with P1/P2 brought out for really long delays.
Here is some more info in Chinese. As one of the comments notes though, an OTP microcontroller at  less than 0.2¥ is cheaper (though you need maybe USD 100-200 worth of stuff to get going- a programmer and an ICE - and that's not an ideal setup).

Thanks, that makes more sense than the garbled stuff, that they have on the ali express site.
